# How to configure mule ESB with Apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, integration, esb, mule

I was asked to introduce Mule ESB to integrate a working logic.
When I was trying to configure mule with Tomcat (Steps given in http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Deploying+Mule+as+a+Service+to+Tomcat).. Tomcat stopped running..!!
I tried to figure out what the error was.. I executed "Catalina.bat run" in cmd prompt and it threw me the following error..

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap initClassLoaders
SEVERE: Class loader creation threw exception
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:396)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:559)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:201)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader(Bootstrap.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:391)
```

Can somebody suggest a detailed solution for this??
If possible can somebody give a detailed procedure to integrate Tomcat with Mule ESB?

Comment: The mulesoft.org link you've posted requires sign-up. Could you post your Tomcat config files to aid with diagnosis? Thanks

Comment: @Dave : Catalina propertiespackage.definition=sun.,java.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.tomcat.,org.apache.jasper. common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/mule-libs/user/*.jar,${catalina.home}/mule-libs/mule/*.jar,${catalina.home}/mule-libs/opt/*.jar                 server.loader= shared.loader=             # String cache configuration. tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled=true

Comment: moreover I've added mule listner in Tomcat server.xml file!! <Listener className="org.mule.module.tomcat.MuleTomcatListener"/> and all the jar files are placed in appropiate places

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Make sure your app name don't contain spaces or special characters.
I would probably also try to place tomcat in the root directory or in a path without spaces.
Also TOMCAT_HOME should not end with "\"